# Extracting number from unicode string with regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode-string

I have the following dictionary which contains some product data:

```
dictionary = {'price': [u'3\xa0590 EUR'],
              'name': [u'Product name with unicode chars]}
```

All values are in unicode. As you can see I'm using lists as dictionary values because sometimes I need to concatenate the information from several different sources.

I'm looking for a way to extract the digits from the price value without the non-breaking space (\xa0) and currency at the end (EUR) by using a regex.

In this case I would like to see the following as a result:

> 3590

Can you please suggest a solution?

[SOLUTION]

Adding the solution here because the comments field wrapped my code unexpectedly:

I used [.sub()](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace) method from Python's `re` module which is a replace function. Here is the final code that gives me the expected result:

```
p = re.compile( '(\xa0| EUR|)')
result = p.sub( '', dictionary['price'][0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about python, but here's a regex:

```
p = /\D/g;
s.replace(p, '');
```

Comment: Thanks! The following implementation works fine. [.sub()](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace) is equals the replace function in Python regex.   `p = re.compile( '(\xa0| EUR|)')
result = p.sub( '', dictionary['price'][0])`